# Combine overflow-y: scroll with overflow-x: visible

Tags: html, css

I have a div, that has flyout divs positioned absolute to the right. Its all working correctly but I need to add a max height to my main div. Since it will overflow, I add overflow-y scroll, but it messes everything up. It prevents my flyout divs from going outside of the main div, and places them inside with a horizontal scrollbar.

I've mocked up an example:

```css
.menu {
  height: 200px;
  max-height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.menu.overflow {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  background-color: purple;
  height: 150px;
  max-height: 150px;
}

.menu-item {
  height: 30px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.menu-item-flyout {
  display: none;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  background-color: green;
  top: 0;
}

.menu-item:hover .menu-item-flyout {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!-- no overflow y scroll -->

working correctly:
<div class="menu">
  <div class="menu-item">
    <div class="menu-item-flyout"></div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="menu-item">
    <div class="menu-item-flyout"></div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="menu-item">
    <div class="menu-item-flyout"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- overflow y scroll -->

This is not working. I want to add overflow y
scroll to menu but it prevents the flyout

<div class="menu overflow">
  <div class="menu-item">
    <div class="menu-item-flyout"></div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="menu-item">
    <div class="menu-item-flyout"></div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="menu-item">
    <div class="menu-item-flyout"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: whats the main div?

Comment: @joshmoto .main

Comment: can you use javascript to overcome this problem?

Comment: i dont see why not @thinker

Comment: I have removed chatty material from your posts before, so I am downvoting this time as a reminder. Please try to keep your posts succinct and free of chat-room material.

Comment: Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately you can't mix overflow values. [Per MDN on `overflow-x`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-x):

> If `overflow-y` is `hidden`, `scroll` or `auto` and this property is `visible`
>   (default) it will implicitly compute to `auto`.

`auto`, in this case, forces a scroll bar. There is no way to get around this: you cannot have a box overflow in only one direction.

As a general principal, menus based on hover are difficult to navigate as they are, but are treacherous from an accessibility standpoint. Adding scroll bars to the mix is a recipe for disaster. I'd recommend approaching the problem from another angle.